# Changing new Tomcat settings from the defaults in STS Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I find myself continually having to delete my Tomcat 7 server in STS Eclipse and re-installing.

Each time I have to then:
a) increase start up time from 45 sec and 
b) increase Tomcat memory by adding something like this on the "VM Arguments" under the "Arguments" tab: "-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:PermSize=512m -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit"

How do you change defaults for a) and b)? Google has plenty of info on changing these one time, but I want to change the defaults for a "new", and on this the search is coming up a blank.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create either `bin/setenv.sh` (for Unix) or `bin/setenv.bat` (for Windows) and add all your `-XX` options there. This file [is not present by default](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/ask-the-experts/configure-tomcat-memory-settings) in Tomcat but if you create one, it will be picked up by startup script.

Whenever you reinstall Tomcat, just back this file up and copy it back.

Comment: Great - now you point that out I find it all over Google. Thanks